# javax.usb.UsbException: Properties file javax.usb.properties not found

Tags: java, usb

I used the following code to get the manufacturerCode of the usb device attached to the system. I added the jsr80-1.0.1 jar. And I got the following error javax.usb.UsbException:

> Properties file javax.usb.properties not found.

Any suggestions?

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.usb.*;

    public class USBListener {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try{
                UsbServices services = UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();
                UsbHub root = services.getRootUsbHub();
                listDevices(root);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        public static void listDevices(UsbHub hub) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, UsbException {
            List devices = hub.getAttachedUsbDevices();
            Iterator iterator = devices.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)iterator.next();
                describe(device);
                if(device.isUsbHub()) {
                    System.out.println("is hub");
                }
            }
        }

        public static void describe(UsbDevice device) 
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException, UsbException {
            UsbDeviceDescriptor descriptor = device.getUsbDeviceDescriptor();
            byte manufacturerCode = descriptor.iManufacturer();
            System.out.println("Manufacturer index: " + manufacturerCode);
            System.out.println("Manufacturer String: " + device.getString(manufacturerCode));
            System.out.println("USB version: " + decodeBCD(descriptor.bcdUSB()));
            System.out.println("Maximum control packet size: " + descriptor.bMaxPacketSize0());

        }

        public static String decodeBCD(short bcd) {
            int upper = (0xFF00 & bcd) >> 8;
            int middle = (0xF0 & bcd) >> 4;
            int lower = 0x0F & bcd;
            return upper + "." + middle + "." + lower;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need this file on your classpath. From the docs:

> The javax.usb.properties file is a Java properties file that is
>   required by the API implementation loader class. The properties file
>   must be loadable by normal means (i.e. it must be in the CLASSPATH)
>   and it must contain the property javax.usb.services. This property
>   must be defined. Its value must be the fully qualified class name of a
>   class that implements the interface javax.usb.UsbServices. This class
>   will be loaded as the implementation of javax.usb.

And further, if you are seeing this error, you presumably haven't got a javax.usb implementation:

> You need a javax.usb implementation; the file is provided by all
>   javax.usb implementations

See here: http://javax-usb.sourceforge.net/faq.html#what_is_properties_file

Comment: Thanks Richard for your answer. I am using windows. where can is get this properties file.

Comment: @Jack - as the docs say, this file is bundled with implementations of javax.usb

Comment: @ Richard -- You mean I need to add javax.usb jar. When I search for that jar I found only jsr80-1.0.1 jar. I already added in my build path.