# howt to set the javax.usb.properties class in mac os

Tags: java, macos, usb

I was develop the usb java program . when it run this program it shows the error like this.

```
       javax.usb.UsbException: Properties file javax.usb.properties not found.
```

so i dont no set the properties file on mac os . 
i am using the mac os. 
so please help me. 
      thanking u

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6913766/679982

Comment: In your original question, there was a link provided to a duplicate question/answer.  Read that, and you'll have your answer.