# How to fix Properties file javax.usb.properties not found

Tags: java, usb

I am creating an java application that is for to get list of attached Usb devices and when i run this i get an error called **Properties file javax.usb.properties not found**.please fix this 
this is my java code:

```
package com.example.sample;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;    
import javax.usb.*;   
public class Usb
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UsbException
    {
            UsbServices services = UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();
            UsbHub root = services.getRootUsbHub();
            listPeripherique(root); 
    }

    private static void listPeripherique(UsbHub hub) {
        List perepheriques = hub.getAttachedUsbDevices();
        Iterator iterator = perepheriques.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          UsbDevice perepherique = (UsbDevice) iterator.next();
          System.out.println(perepherique);
          if (perepherique.isUsbHub()) {
            listPeripherique((UsbHub) perepherique);
          }
        }           
    }    
}
```

Comment: have you read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913399/javax-usb-usbexception-properties-file-javax-usb-properties-not-found ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java USB library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862880/java-usb-library)

Answer (score 2):

Have you created the javax.usb.properties file ? If not you need to create it, you put it in the folder with all your others files. With inside this file:

`javax.usb.services = org.usb4java.javax.Services`

Have a look to this tutorial: http://usb4java.org/quickstart/javax-usb.html

Answer (score 2):

#### Create resource folder

- Right click on Java Resources > New > Source Folder
- At Project name, click Browse button > choose your project name
- At Folder name, enter your folder name as **resource** > click on Finish button

#### Create javax.usb.properties

- Right click on resource folder > New > Other > File> click Next button
- Enter File name as **javax.usb.properties**
- Click on javax.usb.properties to open > write this :

If using usb4java lib

```
javax.usb.services = org.usb4java.javax.Services
```